# Rails Gemes versions and the `Gemfile` compiled have problems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I have a very big project developed in certain test version, the project run well, but there are a problem with the `rspec`, the `Gemfile` and the `Gemfile.lock`, some of the developers have updated some gems but didn't remove the old `Gemfile.lock`, so we did not had any problem with the project because the `Gemfile` not crashed with the project.
TOO MANY commits after, I found the problem, I think is for the differences beetween gems.

**When I copy and paste the last version of the `Gemfile.lock` all the specs run well, but if I remove the old `Gemfile.lock` and run again the `bundle install` the project will to present many problems with the specs** I think is for the gems version, but I try to install the same version that I have in my old `Gemfile.lock` and I have the same problem, also there are some gems that cannot find the original version.

The project is so big, and I cannot update the `Gemfile`, **I think that one of the possible solution is with a program convert the `Gemfile.lock` to `Gemfile` to not have any error with my specs**

This is my old `Gemfile.lock` that makes run my rspec well:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    aasm (3.0.3)
      activerecord
    actionmailer (3.2.1)
      actionpack (= 3.2.1)
      mail (~> 2.4.0)
    actionpack (3.2.1)
      activemodel (= 3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.1)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.2)
    active_median (0.0.1)
    active_record_query_trace (1.5.4)
    activemodel (3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.1)
      activemodel (= 3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
      arel (~> 3.0.0)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.1)
      activemodel (= 3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
    activesupport (3.2.1)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.2.7)
    akami (1.0.0)
      gyoku (>= 0.4.0)
    algorithms (0.5.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    awesome_nested_set (2.1.6)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    bluepill (0.0.66)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 4.0.0)
      daemons (~> 1.1.4)
      i18n (>= 0.5.0)
      state_machine (~> 1.1)
    bourne (1.6.0)
      mocha (~> 1.1)
    builder (3.0.0)
    cancan (1.6.7)
    capistrano (2.11.2)
      highline
      net-scp (>= 1.0.0)
      net-sftp (>= 2.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.14)
      net-ssh-gateway (>= 1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    database_cleaner (0.7.2)
    debugger (1.6.8)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2.0)
      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.3.5)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.8)
    devise (2.0.4)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.1.1)
    devise_lastseenable (0.0.6)
      devise
      rails (>= 3.0.4)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    exception_notification (2.6.1)
      actionmailer (>= 3.0.4)
    execjs (1.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    factory_girl (3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (3.0.0)
      factory_girl (~> 3.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faraday (0.7.6)
      addressable (~> 2.2)
      multipart-post (~> 1.1)
      rack (~> 1.1)
    geocoder (1.1.1)
    groupdate (1.0.4)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
    gyoku (0.4.4)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    highline (1.6.11)
    hike (1.2.1)
    holidays (3.3.0)
    httpi (0.9.6)
      rack
    i18n (0.6.0)
    i18n-inflector (2.6.6)
      i18n (>= 0.4.1)
    journey (1.0.3)
    json (1.6.5)
    kaminari (0.13.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    metaclass (0.0.4)
    mime-types (1.18)
    mocha (1.2.1)
      metaclass (~> 0.0.1)
    multi_json (1.1.0)
    multipart-post (1.1.5)
    net-scp (1.0.4)
      net-ssh (>= 1.99.1)
    net-sftp (2.0.5)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.9)
    net-ssh (2.9.2)
    net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
      net-ssh (>= 1.99.1)
    newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317)
    nokogiri (1.5.2)
    nori (1.1.0)
    oauth (0.4.5)
    oauth-plugin (0.4.0.rc2)
      multi_json
      oauth (~> 0.4.4)
      oauth2
      rack
    oauth2 (0.5.2)
      faraday (~> 0.7)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    orm_adapter (0.0.7)
    passenger (5.0.28)
      rack
      rake (>= 0.8.1)
    pg (0.18.4)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rabl (0.6.2)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.14)
      multi_json (~> 1.1.0)
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-protection (1.2.0)
      rack
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.1)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.1)
      actionpack (= 3.2.1)
      activerecord (= 3.2.1)
      activeresource (= 3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.1)
    railties (3.2.1)
      actionpack (= 3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (11.1.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redis (2.2.2)
    redis-actionpack (3.2.1)
      actionpack (= 3.2.1)
      redis-rack (~> 1.4.0)
      redis-store (~> 1.1.0)
    redis-activesupport (3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
      redis-store (~> 1.1.0)
    redis-namespace (1.0.3)
      redis (< 3.0.0)
    redis-rack (1.4.1)
      rack (= 1.4.1)
      redis-store (~> 1.1.0)
    redis-rails (3.2.1)
      redis-actionpack (~> 3.2.1)
      redis-activesupport (~> 3.2.1)
      redis-store (~> 1.1.0)
    redis-store (1.1.0)
      redis (~> 2.2.0)
    resque (1.20.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      redis-namespace (~> 1.0.2)
      sinatra (>= 0.9.2)
      vegas (~> 0.1.2)
    resque-scheduler (2.0.0)
      redis (>= 2.0.1)
      resque (>= 1.20.0)
      rufus-scheduler
    resque_mailer (2.0.3)
      actionmailer (>= 3.0.0)
      resque (>= 1.2.3)
    resque_spec (0.12.2)
      resque (>= 1.19.0)
      rspec (>= 2.5.0)
    rspec (2.9.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.9.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.9.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.9.0)
    rspec-core (2.9.0)
    rspec-expectations (2.9.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.3)
    rspec-mocks (2.9.0)
    rspec-rails (2.9.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.9.0)
    rufus-scheduler (2.0.17)
      tzinfo (>= 0.3.23)
    rvm-capistrano (1.0.2)
      capistrano (>= 2.0.0)
    sass (3.1.15)
    sass-rails (3.2.5)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    savon (0.9.9)
      akami (~> 1.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      gyoku (>= 0.4.0)
      httpi (~> 0.9)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)
      nori (~> 1.1)
      wasabi (~> 2.1)
    shoulda-matchers (1.5.6)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      bourne (~> 1.3)
    simplecov (0.6.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.5.3)
    simplecov-html (0.5.3)
    sinatra (1.3.2)
      rack (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.6)
      rack-protection (~> 1.2)
      tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.3)
    slack-notifier (1.5.1)
    sprockets (2.1.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.5)
    state_machine (1.2.0)
    strip_attributes (1.1.0)
      activemodel (~> 3.0)
    sugarcrm (0.9.18)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.10)
      i18n
      json
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    timecop (0.8.1)
    timezone (0.99.2)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    typhoeus (0.3.3)
      mime-types
    tzinfo (0.3.49)
    uglifier (1.2.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    vegas (0.1.11)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    warden (1.1.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    wasabi (2.1.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  aasm
  active_median
  active_record_query_trace
  algorithms
  awesome_nested_set
  bluepill
  cancan
  capistrano
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  database_cleaner (~> 0.7.1)
  debugger
  devise
  devise_lastseenable
  exception_notification (~> 2.6.1)
  factory_girl_rails
  geocoder
  groupdate
  holidays
  i18n-inflector
  kaminari
  net-ssh (= 2.9.2)
  newrelic_rpm
  nokogiri
  oauth-plugin (>= 0.4.0.pre1)
  passenger
  pg
  rabl (~> 0.6.0)
  rails (= 3.2.1)
  redis-rails
  resque (~> 1.20.0)
  resque-scheduler
  resque_mailer (~> 2.0.3)
  resque_spec
  rspec-rails (~> 2.4)
  rvm-capistrano
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  savon (~> 0.9.9)
  shoulda-matchers (~> 1.5.0)
  simplecov
  slack-notifier (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.1)
  sqlite3
  strip_attributes (~> 1.0)
  sugarcrm
  timecop
  timezone
  typhoeus (~> 0.3.3)
  tzinfo (~> 0.3.49)
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.14.6
```

And here is my attemp to copy the `Gemfile.lock` to the `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4', group: [:development, :test, :production]

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'passenger', '~> 5.0.8'
  # gem 'passenger', '~> 5.1.4'
end

gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_lastseenable'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'oauth-plugin', ">= 0.4.0.pre1"

group :test, :development, :vcr do
  gem 'rspec', '~> 1.1.3'
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.99"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.8.0'#, git: 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers.git'
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 0.7.1'
  gem 'simplecov'
end

group :test do
  gem 'resque_spec'
end

gem 'rabl', '~> 0.6.0'
gem 'aasm'
gem 'net-ssh', '=2.9.2'
gem 'holidays', '~> 3.1.2'#, git: 'https://github.com/sincola/holidays.git'
gem 'capistrano', require: false
gem 'rvm-capistrano', require: false
gem 'newrelic_rpm', '~> 3.18.1'

gem 'i18n-inflector'

gem 'savon', '~> 0.9.9'
gem "typhoeus", "~> 0.3.3"

gem "exception_notification", "~> 2.6.1"
gem "strip_attributes", "~> 1.0"

gem 'resque', "~> 1.20.0"
gem 'resque_mailer', "~> 2.0.3"
gem 'resque-scheduler', :require => 'resque_scheduler'

gem 'kaminari'
gem 'redis-rails'
gem 'algorithms'

gem 'geocoder'
gem 'timezone', '~> 1.0'

gem 'sugarcrm'
gem 'bluepill'
gem 'groupdate'
gem 'active_median'

gem 'awesome_nested_set'

gem 'tzinfo', '~> 0.3.49'

gem 'active_record_query_trace' # source: https://github.com/ruckus/active-record-query-trace

gem 'slack-notifier', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.1'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6.5'
```

What I think is: there are different gems that are repeated in my `Gemfile.lock` with different versions in old `Gemfile.lock`

Please read carefully my problem, and If you know how to help my, I would thank you infinitely.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: what error do you get when you try to install without the old Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 1):

When you try to run bundle install, Some gem will give you error like `Your bundle is locked to xyz gem (version), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile`. To resolve such issue you have to update exact version `= xxx` in your `Gemfile` not with `~> xxx`.

Also you might need to update locked gems also in `Gemfile.lock`, due to dependency of other gems.

Comment: Thanks, I can install everything the problem is the spec, I cannot run it with success

Answer (score 1):

The `Gemfile` is less strict than the `Gemfile.lock`. So, all the Gems that have no restriction or a soft restriction (for example, `~> 4` or `> 4.0`) would be updated to a new version, which may not be the one that was used when the code was originally developed, that's why some of the gems may fail.

I hadn't time to do a complete review of your attempt to copy the `Gemfile.lock` to a `Gemfile` yet, but I have seen you used some gems without specifying an exact version in your `Gemfile` and I think that may be your problem. The `Gemfile.lock` always specify the exact version, so if you want to copy your `Gemfile.lock` you should be doing the same. For example, for `slack-notifier` gem you are using version `1.5.1` but your `Gemfile` has `gem 'slack-notifier', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.1'` when it should be `gem 'slack-notifier', '1.5.1'`

Comment: Given it was useful, can you please up vote or approve the answer?